# How to switch between tabs via pushbutton ? using pyqt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I am newbie and maybe this is silly question.
I want to activate tab by clicking on pushButton . If I click pushButton_1 then it shows/activates tab_1, on the clicking pushButton_2 switches to tab_2, and so on . Bellow there is pic how I tried it but without success. Help me solve this and write correct code down. Thank you in advance.

This is my code :

```
from spex import *
import sys



class speX (Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.setupUi(window)
        self.systemButton.clicked.setCurrentIndex(self, 0)
        self.cpuButton.clicked.setCurrentIndex(self, 1)



app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

ui = speX (MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

I want this - when I click systemButton, activate tab indexed as 0, when click cpuButton activate tab indexed as 1.

Error provided there -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\spex\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    ui = speX (MainWindow)
  File "d:\spex\main.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.systemButton.clicked.setCurrentIndex(self, 0)
AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtBoundSignal' object has no attribute 'setCurrentIndex'
```

This is example of my project - pyuic5 ui to py code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'D:/spex/example.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(763, 611)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 70, 361, 361))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.page)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 310, 193, 28))
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.commandLinkButton = QtWidgets.QCommandLinkButton(self.page_2)
        self.commandLinkButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 190, 222, 48))
        self.commandLinkButton.setObjectName("commandLinkButton")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 110, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 190, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 763, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.commandLinkButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CommandLinkButton"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please share your code as text in your question, not using images. Read more about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). Also, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've got so far (even if it doesn't work), ensuring that it includes as much as possible (but not *too much*, it has to be reproducible, but still *minimal*).

Comment: can you check it now ?

Comment: Your code is still incomplete, you're using a `Ui_MainWindow` class, but you didn't provide it.

Comment: @RomanSmith You probably should use ```QStackedWidget``` for this. ```setCurrentIndex()``` function can't be used like this.

Comment: I just convert ui to py via pyuic5 , which I created in  qt designer. There is not anything different . There is 6 buttons and 6 tabs. Then everything is simple. I want to click first button to activate first tab, second button - second tab.

Comment: @deepanshu can you write here some example ?

Comment: @RomanSmith, it's a multipage application then. I would suggest you to use **QStackedWidget** because **setCurrentIndex()** can't be used this way. It's not available to a QPushButton.

Comment: @RomanSmith we need the code generated from pyuic, while we may already know what's wrong with your code, we cannot help you blindly. Provide the file created with pyuic too.

Comment: @RomanSmith in the provided ui there's no trace of `systemButton` nor `cpuButton`.

Comment: This was just an example . There is no matter if it is called systemButton or pushButton. Then I have just renamed it.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to be more careful with the code you provide. When we ask you for a minimal **reproducible** example, it means that we *must* be able to copy, paste and run your code with minimal (or, better no) editing. We can't help you if you don't help us, and you can't expect us to "patch" all missing or misplaced parts of your code. People gets easily annoyed if they don't see this kind of efforts, and you might end up losing the opportunity for an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qt, a *signal* is emitted when a particular event occurs: a button is clicked, some text is changed, etc.

Signals are then connected to *slots*, which are functions that can react in some way to those signals. For example, you can create a *slot* that changes the text in a label, and connect it to a `clicked` signal of a button: then, when you click on that button, the text is changed.

Why your code does not work?
Well, for instance, `setCurrentIndex` is a method of a QStackedWidget (similarly to a QTabWidget), so the following doesn't make much sense:

```
    self.systemButton.clicked.setCurrentIndex(self, 0)
```

Where is the reference to the stacked widget?

In PyQt, you can connect signals and slots like this:

```
    someObject.signal.connect(someFunction)
```

Note that `someFunction` is a *reference* to that function; the following will *not* work:

```
    someObject.signal.connect(someFunction())
```

If you want to change the index of a stacked widget after clicking on a button, you have to create a function that changes that index, and connect it to the clicked signal.

```
class speX (Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.setupUi(window)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.goToSecondPage)

    def goToSecondPage(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
```

I strongly suggest you to carefully study how [python classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) work and, generally speaking, the Object Oriented programming paradigm.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance and for your tips, I will consider them all.

Answer (score 1):

The simplist solution would be to connect your buttons to a function that changes the tab index on click

```
tabs = QtWidget.QTabWidget()
tab1 = QtWidget.QWidget()
tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab 1")

systemButton.clicked.connect(tabIndex0)

def tabIndex0():
    tabs.setCurrentIndex(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I was trying to do something like this. This also helped me. Thank you again.